# response is: {status: error, message: All fields are needed.} While calling Api in flutter this will be come in output in cmd

Tags: android, json, flutter, api, dart

The response is: {status: error, message: All fields are needed.} While calling Api in a flutter this will come in output in cmd. why I am getting this error? Some help me I am new to Flutter for the backend.

API Calling Code is determined

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String globalUrl = 'https://dev.eigix.com/connevents/api/Webservices/signup/';

Future sendpostrequest(action, parameters, BuildContext context) async {
  var url = Uri.parse(globalUrl + action);
  //print('url is: $url');
  //print('parameters are: $parameters');
  parameters = json.encode(parameters);

  var response = await http.post(url,
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: parameters);
  //var response = await http.post(url, body: parameters);
  print('response for $action is ${response.body}');
  var res = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (res['status'] != null && res['status'] != '') {
    print('sending proper response.');
    return res;
  } else {
    print('status code is: ${response.statusCode}');
    print('sending error response.');
    return response.statusCode;
  }
}

showErrorDialog(BuildContext context) {
  // Create button
  Widget okButton = TextButton(
    child: Text("OK"),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    },
  );

  // Create AlertDialog
  AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
    title: Text("Error Occured!"),
    content: Text("Error occured while processing your request."),
    actions: [
      okButton,
    ],
  );

  // show the dialog
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return alert;
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: you are not passing the param in API

Comment: can you explain in detail.!
because I'm stuck on this for four days.